# How to test whether HTML is loaded from file system or via http protocol

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a javascript test in an html page that can determine if the html file was launched when being online, or being launched from someones hard disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is

```
var fromHDD=window.location.href.indexOf('file://')==0;
```

or

```
var fromHDD=window.location.protocol=='file:';
```